# Writing big strings to a text file?

Tags: java, text, csv, text-files

I have strings which look like this -

```
String text = "item1, item2, item3, item4 etc..."
```

I made java code to write these strings to a text file which will be converted to csv by simply changing the extension. The logic is - **print a string, then move to new line and print another string.**

Output in text file was perfect when test strings had only **10-20 items.**

BUT, my real strings have about **3000 unique items each**. There are about **20,000 such strings**.

When i write all these strings to the text file, it gets messed up. 
I see **3000 rows instead of 20,000 rows**.

I think there is no need for code for this problem because its been done and tested.
I only need to be able to format my data properly.

For those who want to see the code -

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Texty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("start");

        String str = "";
        String enter = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );

        for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
            str = str + i + ",";

        }

            str = str + 5; 
        System.out.println(str);

        FileWriter fw = null;
        File newTextFile = new File("C:\\filez\\output.txt");
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

             fw.write(str + enter);

            }

            fw.close();

        } catch (IOException iox) {
            //do stuff with exception
            iox.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("stop");

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you're using to write the text file...

Comment: can you post a bit of your code? we can't help you if we don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that there is no difference between 10 columns and 3000 columns, you just have longer lines

Also there is no difference between 10 rows and 20,000 rows, you juts have more lines.

While you can have much, much larger files in Java or on your files system, some old versions of excel could not load so many columns (it had a limit of 256 columns) or such large files (it had a limit of about 1 GB of raw data)

I would check the file is correct in another program e.g. one you wrote and you might find all the data is there.

If the data is not there, you have a bug, There is no limitation in Java or Windows or Linux which would explain the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: I made some lame mistakes. :( The computer is right and I am wrong...as usual.

Comment: One definition of a "Computer Expert" - `Someone who has made all the mistakes before`.  How do you think I guessed the problem wasn't what you thought it was ;)